# How do I update a text entity contained within a window panel in Ursina?

Tags: python, user-interface, ursina

Essentially, I am trying to have a scoreboard, which upon completion of a task, opens the scoreboard and displays what your score is. However, whenever I run the actual task, it displays the initial value instead of the new variable value. How could I update this value within the window panel?

Sample Pseudocode:

```
from ursina import *

score=0

def challenge():
    score += 2
    wp.enabled=True

app = Ursina()

wp = WindowPanel(content=(Text('text' + str(score))) popup=True, enabled=False)

start = Button(parent=scene, text='start', on_click=challenge)

app.run()
```

Comment: It won't update automatically because the expression `Text('text' + str(score))` is only evaluated once. In this simple use case, you could recreate the popup every time you need it instead of trying to change an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the text entity to a variable first:

```
text_entity = Text('text' + str(score))
wp = WindowPanel(content=(text_entity,) popup=True, enabled=False)

# to update the text
text_entity.text = 'new text'
```

Comment: It's also possible to do wp.content[0].text = 'new text', but it's a bit less readable and you depends on the order.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your not assigning a variable to the Text which is bad. See:

```py
wp = WindowPanel(content=(Text('text' + str(score))) popup=True, enabled=False)
```

When You assign it, you can change the information and content.

```py
text = Text('text' + str(score))
wp = WindowPanel(content=(text) popup=True, enabled=False)
```

If you want to do something like if a key is pressed, then see this code:

```py
text = Text('text' + str(score))
wp = WindowPanel(content=(text) popup=True, enabled=False)

def update():
```